# Schemacrawler partition large schema based on number of tables

Tags: schemacrawler

I have a use case where I am using schemacrawler to crawl metadata from various databases. And use the metadata later on in my downstream system.

I have lot of variable size databases to crawl. The number of tables vary from 20-2000. Now, I am using Schemacrawler APIs to run the crawler. If the number of tables in the source database is more my application crashes because it tries to crawl all the tables at once.

Is there any way in schemacrawler to crawl a database in batches. i.e. if there are 1000 tables, it crawls in 5 batches, 200 tables each?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Himangshu,

SchemaCrawler is designed with the premise that you should narrow your search to a small number of tables, rather than trying to obtain the entire schema. SchemaCrawler provides powerful ways to filter search results using regular expressions. That being said, I understand your use case. I suggest that you use the "minimum" schema info level to obtain a list of all the tables, and then write code to obtain details of a few tables at a time using the list.

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](https://www.schemacrawler.com/)